# Content By Query filtered by managed metadata, unfiltered view = all items?

Tags: managed-metadata, content-query-web-part

This might be an easy peasy question, but I cant seem to find an answer.

I have a list and some managed metadata that I use to filter it with a content by query web part. The managed metadata acts as navigation in the top navigation bar, and when clicking you end up at a page layout containing the Content By Query Webpart, this page layout is also the Home Page of the site.

Now the problem is of course that when I first arrive at the site root, I have not clicked any managed metadata filter and thus the Content By Query WP does not display any list items while I'd like it to display ALL items as default.

UPDATE: Apparently it just works now, I must have missed something. The CQWP will display all items when no navigation term is set.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm- if you filter your CQWP using PageQueryString then if it is empty then it will display all items.  Could you add your metadata filter value to your query string when clicking on the navigation?

```
http://server/site/page.aspx?filter=value
```

Then in your CQWP you use:

```
[PageQueryString:filter]
```

Comment: I'd rather not change from the "Filter by navigation term" default behavior if I dont have to, so I'll look into a solution through that first. Thanks for the suggestion. / Richard